# What library to use with Django to develop an interactive web app for the Energy Hub model?

Tags: web-apps, python, react, django

**Energy Hub** is an interconnection of energy streams (Electricity, Heat, Gas, etc.), energy converters (Heat Pump, PV panel, etc.) and storages (Battery, Hot Water Tank, etc). Typically, a house can be called an energy hub. When many hubs are linked together (via links that can transfer energy between them), we call it a **Multiple Hub.**

We form an optimization problem for an energy hub (or multiple hubs) whose solution tells the total costs required to meet the electrical and heat demands (specified as timeseries) of the hub.

Currently, we specify the hub model via an excel file listing out all storages, converters, their capacities, efficiencies, time series of loads, etc.

This excel file is then converted to a multilevel python dictionary containing all the data about the hub (this dictionary is equivalent to the hub and to the excel file). A sample hub looks like the following:
[image: An image showing how an energy hub looks like; with the colored lines as streams, light grey boxes as converters, dark ones as storages]
*In this image, colored lines are streams, light grey boxes are converters, dark ones are storages.*

Then we impose constraints on the model and solve it. The whole codebase is in python.

The requirement is to get rid of the excel file and to be able to build a model interactively. Instead of adding columns in the excel file, we want the user to be able to simply drag and drop elements (as in the image above) and create the energy hub.

We also want to be able to connect multiple hubs together via links. Note that we currently have two types of excel files:

- ones which define hubs as stated above (one file per hub), and
- ones which define a network of hubs (one file per network of hubs
  containing information about how the hubs are linked).

Both types of excel files are converted to respective python dictionaries (as many as are excel files). These dictionaries are used in the code which performs optimization.

*We need to build these dictionaries from an interactive diagram instead of building them from excel files.*

Here is an idea sketch of the web app:[image: Image showing how the app should look like]

More specifically we are looking for the following features:

1. **Should be able drag-and-drop elements.**
2. **Write text associated with a component:** e.g. efficiency, name, lifetime, etc. are text pieces associated with a converter. The
   hover on component should display these and these should be editable on clicking the component.
3. **Connect nodes and components:** Connections should have a direction. If a converter (which inputs a form of energy and outputs another form(s) ) is connected to multiple streams (incoming and outgoing), the corresponding fields in
   dictionary ('input' and 'output') must fill themselves. We need a smart app which avoids text as far as possible. (The diagram above at once
   ascertains most of the fields in the excel, these need not be
   explicitly entered by the user).
4. **Well integration with python:** Since the whole code is in python, we want flexibility in that people should be able to edit the
   dictionary directly, see it being built in real time, call functions by pressing buttons i.e. the app should be able to communicate with python code and vice-versa.
5. **Interconvertibility:** The app should be able to generate dictionary from the diagram as well as the reverse.
6. **Store state of the sketch:** So that it can be saved even if incomplete and retrieved from that saved state to be modified later
   on.
7. **Export the sketch in understandable text:** It is preferred that the 'understandable text' be the python dictionary itself.
8. **Specify Multiple Hubs:** User should be able to specify whether he is building a 'multiple-hub-model' or a 'single-hub-model'. For a 'multiple-hub-model', he should be able to join hubs via links. As soon as 'multiple-hub-model' option is selected, the app should start building the second type of python dictionary which corresponds to the network of hubs.
9. **Advanced features:**

   - Error messages (if the 'optimize' button is pressed without specifying a critical value in the sketch) in real time,
   - Be able to pull the solar irradiance data (input for PV panel) from the internet (based on the location of the hub entered by the user).

I want to use Django because it integrates well with python. **Which libraries should be used to achieve the above?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Programming approaches advice is off-topic here. Please either ask for an existing app, or for a library that satisfies a well-defined need. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Could you direct me to the relevant stack exchange website where I can get an answer to my question? Thanks.

Comment: As it is now, I don't think there is any, unfortunately. But you could modify it a bit to make it on-topic here. Please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/are-questions-about-software-technologies-acceptable and https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/should-programming-language-recommendations-be-allowed-here first.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Is it on-topic now? I have changed the title and the ending of the question. I am looking for suggestions, therefore can't be more specific without losing the gist. Thanks for those links.